# wso2 is secondary user store authentication

Tags: authentication, ldap, wso2, oauth-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I have a wso2 is 5.1.0 server runign on Debian. I have a simple servlet that is authenticating using Oauth2 and works perfectly with the users in the primary store.

I have created a secondary store pointing to an openldap server. I have some users and groups and are seen correctly from the IS. I see that when I try to see the User Profile i get the following error:

```
Error while loading user profile metadata
```

But when I try to authenticate using the users in the ldap server i get a Login Failed error. I have tried to use both username, DOMAIN/username and username@DOMAIN but none of the worked.

I am starting to think that it could be related to the Calim configuration as the users in the different stores have different values but I don't know how to solve it.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

UPDATED:

This is how I have defined the secondary store.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
      <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://xxxx:389</Property>
      <Property name="ConnectionName">cn=admin,dc=xx,dc=xx</Property>
      <Property encrypted="true" name="ConnectionPassword">xxxx</Property>
      <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=users,dc=nextel,dc=es</Property>
      <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">inetOrgPerson</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameAttribute">cn</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)cn=?))</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
      <Property name="UserDNPattern"/>
      <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute"/>
      <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
      <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
      <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=groups,dc=xx,dc=xx</Property>
      <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
      <Property name="RoleDNPattern"/>
      <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
      <Property name="MemberOfAttribute"/>
      <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Username pattern policy violated.</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password pattern policy violated.</Property>
      <Property name="RoleNameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="RoleNameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="BulkImportSupported">true</Property>
      <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
      <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
      <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
      <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
      <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="defaultRealmName">WSO2.ORG</Property>
      <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
      <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="ReadTimeout">5000</Property>
      <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
      <Property name="RetryAttempts">0</Property>
      <Property name="DomainName">incloudLDAP</Property>
      <Property name="Description"/>
</UserStoreManager>
```

I can see the users in the list and even create a new one on the LDAP through WSO2 Is, but i cannot see the parameters.

UPDATED:

THe user structure in the LDAP is quite simple.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the authentication issue, you need to verify "UserNameSearchFilter" attribute is correctly configured. It must mapped to the user name attribute in your ladp server.

```
<Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=user)(cn=?))</Property>
```

Also you can map attibutes from different user stores to a same wso2 claim. In the mapped attibute section use something like follows,

```
PRIMARY/attribute1;FOO/attribute2;BAR/attribute3
```

Also refer - https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Adding+Claim+Mapping

Comment: As I understand UserNameSearchFilter is correctly defined (see update). I don't really understand how the claims work.

Comment: ok. let's say you have two user stores as FOO and BAR. Both user store keeps users' first name but in different attributes. FOO keeps first name in 'fn' and BAR keeps it in 'bfn'. Then we have to tell to identity server if you are gonna get first name from FOO use 'fn' and if you gonna get it from BAR use 'bfn'. So we can express that statement in the mapped attribute section as, FOO/fn;BAR/bfn

Comment: Also can you browse a test user from a ldap viewer(like Apache Directory Studio) and provide a screen shot of user attributes?

Comment: So, to create the claims, do I have to create a new claim dialect and a claim? What should the Dialect Uri and Claim Uri be?

Comment: You don't have to create new claims or new claim dialect. You have to add the correct mapped attribute for the claims you have enabled in the user profile according to the user store attributes.

Comment: I have modified the http://wso2.org/claims claim so only the minimal attributes are required and I have included the reference to the same ones in the secondary LDAP. I have included as DOMAINNAME/value. I am able to see and create user in the LDAP from the WSO IS interface. But I cannot see the User profile (Error while loading user profile metadata) of any remote user. I also cannot logging with those users. I am trying both with DOMAINNAME/username and username.